# problem with name being too long for moderncv title

Tags: moderncv

Is there a way to fit the whole "jesse jaanila | curriculum vitae" title on the same row with the banking style. My simplified code shows that with the font fouriernc that I like, it doesn't seem to fit on a single row.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,finnish]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
 \usepackage{babel}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fouriernc}
 \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

 \firstname{XXX}
 \familyname{XXX}

 \title{Curriculum Vit\ae{}}

\mobile{+358 45 2580 777}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
 \makecvtitle
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,finnish]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
 \usepackage{babel}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{fouriernc}
 \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

 \makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \setlength{\maketitlewidth}{\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\maketitlewidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % detailed information
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomaketitle[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
      \flushmaketitle\@firstmaketitleelementtrue\\}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \addtomaketitle{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomaketitle{\@extrainfo}}%
    \flushmaketitle}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle

 \makeatother

 \firstname{Jesse}
 \familyname{Jaanila}

 \title{Curriculum Vit\ae{}}
\address{Mannerheimintie 21--23 C 38}{00250 \textsc{HELSINKI}}
\mobile{+358 45 2580 777}
\email{jesse.jaanila@aalto.fi}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
 \makecvtitle
 \end{document}
```

The problem is that the `\maketitle` definition in the banking style arbitrarily redefines the length `\maketitlewidth` to be 80% of `\textwidth` so you cannot change that from outside the macro definition.
The quick and dirty hack here is to copy over the original definition from `moderncvstylebanking.sty` and modify the first line so that `\maketitlewidth` is set to the full `\textwidth`. A better patch would just remove that line altogether from the definition so that you can set the `\maketitlewidth` in your preamble to adjust it to your preferences.

Answer (score 10):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

With `moderncv` v2.0, the command to be patched is no more `\maketitle` but `\makehead` and the length to be changed is now `\makeheaddetailswidth`, so the correct patch for this version is

```
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
```

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

Making it a little simpler, you can patch `\maketitle` through the `\patchcmd` command from `etoolbox` (loaded by `moderncv`) so to set the length `\maketitlewidth` to `\textwidth`.

That is, add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,finnish]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Jesse}
\familyname{Jaanila}

\title{Curriculum Vit\ae{}}
\address{Mannerheimintie 21--23 C 38}{00250 \textsc{HELSINKI}}
\mobile{+358 45 2580 777}
\email{jesse.jaanila@aalto.fi}

\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{0.8\textwidth}}
  {\setlength{\maketitlewidth}{\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
 \makecvtitle
 \end{document}
```

[image]